# Search movie data base by rating

Tags: imdbpy

I've trying to find a module or library (or API) that will let me query a movie database by rating. Rotten Tomatos or IMDb are fine. I have a request for a Rotten Tomatoes API key, and I do have a IMDb one, but I can't find any documemtation on how to query the database and return a list of all movies with a certain rating.

If anyone has a solution, I'd very much appreciate it.

Comment: this may be helpful https://www.themoviedb.org/documentation/api/discover

Answer (score 0):

If you want to operate offline, you can consider the [IMDbPY](http://imdbpy.sourceforge.net/) library, which allows you to work with both the online and [offline](http://www.imdb.com/interfaces) set of data of IMDb.

Working offline, basically, you use it to import the plain text data files distributed by IMDb on a SQL database, and then access that data (rating, number of votes and votes distribution are available).
You can't programmatically query movies by rating, but that data is easily accessible from the db itself.